# string.parse("(") error

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a file which contains data as follows:

```
recv(1178884, NULL, 4294967267, 0)      = 0
......
......
```

My source code is:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\smsTrace.txt"))) {
    String sCurrentLine;

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String sysCallName = sCurrentLine;
        String[] sysCallTokens = sysCallName.split("(");
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I split with `sysCallName.split(",")` it works fine but when I use as above, it throws following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
(
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at fileReading.main(fileReading.java:19)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have to escape the opening bracket:

```
sysCallName.split("\\(");
```

Because `split()` expects a regular expression, and brackets are used to mark capturing groups in a regex. So they need to be in pairs. If you just want a bracket it needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 17):

[`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as splitting criteria. Now, `(` in regex is used for capturing groups, so you need to escape it, if you want to match it.

**You have two ways: -**

1. Escape the bracket: -

   ```
   sysCallName.split("\\(");
   ```
2. Use `Character class`: -

   ```
   sysCallName.split("[(]");
   ```

In a character class, all the meta-characters, loose their special meaning, so a `(` is just a `(`, and a `dot(.)` is just a `dot(.)`. Personally, I prefer the 2nd option, as it looks more clear.

Comment: Personally I prefer the first option (just because I'm used to it). Do you know if there are any performance differences?

Comment: @jlordo. AFAIK, no, as such there is not much performance difference. It's just the matter of readability or personal choice.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I assume the second method also allows you to put in any character, regardless of whether or not it'd have to be escaped whereas the first option may not always like that.

Answer (score 6):

escape your string. instead of

```
sysCallName.split("(");
```

try

```
sysCallName.split("\\(");
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add an escape char:

```
String[] sysCallTokens = sysCallName.split("\\(");
```

Answer (score 4):

`(` is a reserved character for regular expressions

You can fix this by prefixing it with a backslash: `\(`

Answer (score 4):

While trying to split with special characters you need to use `\\` with your special character. so here try like this

```
sysCallName.split("\\(");
```

you can find splitting strings with other special characters from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/java/insights/618869-splitting-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this line in your code

```
String[] sysCallTokens = sysCallName.split("\\(");
```

(Just added escape character before the opening bracket)

Answer (score 3):

You can try **[Pattern.quote](http://tutorialdata.com/)** like:

```
sysCallName.split(Pattern.quote(")"));
```

If you want to split any string using special characters, you can use the above method.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the data like it was an array:

```
String[] result = line.split("\\\\(")[1].split("\\\\)").split(",");
```